# How to store output from a bash command?

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x

I need to write a simple python (python3) script to store my local Ip address in a variable in order to manipulate it later, I read a lot around but I don't understand where I'm doing wrong here a chunk of code for a better understanding..

```
#!/usr/bin/env pyhton3
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import fileinput
localip = subprocess.call(["ifconfig | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d ':' -f2 | grep 'Bcast' | cut -d ' ' -f1"], shell=True)
print localip
...
...
...
```

now when I excecute it it prints me this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents $ python change.py
192.168.1.6
0
```

It seems I can't find a solution to this on my own, can anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong and help me out? thanks.

Comment: As explained in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), the value returned by `subprocess.call` is the command's return code, which is used to indicate whether the command succeeded. In this case it is zero, because there was no error.

Comment: Don't go out to the shell to get info about your network interface.  I don't know if this is the canonical solution, but it took all of 10 seconds to find https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces/

Answer (score 2):

To address your [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), why not just use Python itself to get your IP / hostname?

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostname()
'MY-COMPUTER'
>>> socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
'192.168.1.126'
>>> socket.getfqdn()
'my-computer.local'
>>> socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
'192.168.1.126'
```

Answer (score 1):

In python2, you'd do:

```
stdout = subprocess.check_output(args, shell=true)
```

In python3, you can also do:

```
completed_process = subprocess.run(args, shell=True)
stdout = completed_process.stdout
```

Which might be a more useful interface